# Display to client only if collection exists on mongoDB Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema model defined on Mongoose:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var IngredientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    number:Number,
    exist:Boolean,
    photoName:String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Ingredient", IngredientSchema);
```

And I want to display on a web page a different result depending on whether there is an Ingredient already created on database or not.

Here's what I tried so far (but it doesn't work):

```HTML
<!-- Check if inventory is empty or not, and display accordingly -->
<% if ( ! ingredients) { %>

    <p>Add you first ingredient to the inventory !!</p>

<% } else { %>

    <%  ingredients.forEach(function(ingredient) { %>
    ... 
    ...
```

And here's my route:

```js
// Index route
app.get("/inventory", function(req, res) {
    Ingredient.find({}, function(err, allIngredients) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("inventory", { ingredients:allIngredients });        
        }
    })
})
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `if(ingredients.length > 0)` because `ingredients` is an "array". It's never undefined, but when there is no results, it is empty.

Comment: @NeilLunn Your solution also works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the length of ingredients array:

```
<!-- Check if inventory is empty or not, and display accordingly -->
    <% if (!ingredients.length) { %>

        <p>Add you first ingredient to the inventory !!</p>

    <% } else { %>

        <%  ingredients.forEach(function(ingredient) { %>
        ... 
        ...
```